# add array elements with increment operators

Tags: c++, c

in the below code i am trying to add two elements of array with the increment operator, but i am getting the output sum to be wrong. kindly help me if i made any mistake in the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
int a[2];
int top=-1;
a[++top]=10;
a[++top]=20;
printf("a0 is %d \n",a[0]);
printf("a1 is %d \n",a[top]);
printf("value of sum is %d \n",a[top]+a[--top]);
}
```

the output of last line should be 30 as i and summing the two values in a array. but the out put i get is as follows

```
a0 is 10 
a1 is 20 
value of sum is 20
```

Comment: [*warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'top' \[-Wunsequenced\]*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0235e7909cd2da0d)

Comment: STEP AWAY FROM THE PRE/POSTINCREMENT OPERATORS. NOW.

Comment: Again, the C specification should require that compliant compilers detect this garbage, output an extraordinarily nasty error message, and abort the compilation. That saves the OP from being baffled by his own ...

Comment: I just copied and pasted the code in the question and compiled it, and I could not reproduce the OP's problem.  I got 30 as the final sum.  Does the issue in the question vary between compilers and versions of `C`?  I used `gcc 4.8.1` with the `-std=c99` option.

Answer (score 4):

Your program has unspecified behavior. In the expression `a[top]+a[--top]`, the C and C++ language standards do not specify which of `a[top]` and `a[--top]` will be evaluated first, and they don't specify when the `--` operator is executed relative to other expressions. Compilers can evaluate this as they see fit. Yours is computing `--top` first, setting `top` to 0, and then is calculating `a[0]+a[0]`, yielding 20.

Don't use a variable twice in an expression in which you pre- or post- increment or decrement it.

Answer (score 1):

To understand why this is happening, change your last printf to print out `top` and the sum in one line, like this:

```
printf("top is %d and the value of the sum is %d \n",top,a[top]+a[--top]);
```

This should make it apparent that the pre-increment operation is not happening at the point in execution that you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Try to calculate and print

```
int y1 = a[top]; 
int y1 += a[--top]; 

top = 1;
int y2 = a[top] + a[--top];
```

this could help you. 
The point is that the execution of a[--top]; in your code is done before the execution of a[top] because they are not specified.

Answer (score -1):

Here, in this line:

```
printf("value of sum is %d \n",a[top]+a[--top]);
```

Due to *--top*, top becomes 0 again (--top is --1).
Then a[0] and a[0] are added, and it does not give expected output.
I think it's due to high precedence order of -- operator.

As has been said already, it's better to calculate separately and then print.

*PS: Please tell me if anything of the above is wrong or not fully correct. I like to learn from mistakes.*

Comment: Precedence isn't relevant here ... it only applies when operators are adjacent at the same level of expression, e.g., in `expr+expr*expr`, the precedence determines that it is evaluated as `expr+(expr*expr)` rather than `(expr+expr)*expr`. It the OP's case, the language simply doesn't specify when `--` is evaluated relative to the evaluation of `a[top]` ... if it happens before, you get 20. If it happens after, you get 30. A conforming implementation can do it either way.

Comment: To my understanding, the `--` is evaluated before a statement if it's a preincrement operator and after a statement if it's a postincrement operator. In OP's case, it's a preincrement operator and therefore, it's evaluated before the `printf`

Comment: @NoobCoder Your understanding is completely incorrect. Pre vs. post only determine the value of the primary expression they appear in (e.g., if x is 10, the value of ++x is 11 and the value of x++ is 10); they have no bearing on when the operator is evaluated. See my answer, and the "Undefined behavior and sequence points" link at the top of the page.

Comment: @NoobCoder P.S. If you had read the comments under your own answer, you would know that your understanding couldn't possibly be correct.

Comment: Okay, I see. So, it is a compiler-based issue ultimately?